# Appropriate settings for importing unlit Maya models into Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I am not using lighting in my game in Unity3d and all models have lighting baked in their textures, then which of the two methods of importing models is better.

(import settings in Unity inspector).

1. importing models with no normals
2. importing with normals.
3. importing with calculate normals and setting the smoothing angle to 180.

The shader I'm using does not use normals so I don't have a problem with no normal importing.
The 1st method reduces the vertex count most. But I'm wondering if no normals reduces some of the optimisations such as back face culling etc.

In short which is the best settings for importing models if no lighting is used.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it. Before using a tag, make sure you have clicked it and learned what it is used for.

Comment: @Gkills Please have a look at the edits I've just made. Make sure you use proper capitalization in your posts. There are even filters in place which might prevent you from making the post if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing without normals will work for the specific case you're mentioning: prelit models that don't do any shading at all. However, if you want any angle-based effects at all (fresnel highlights or toon shading, for example) you'll need normal information.

You will get better optimization on the model if you don't have normal information, since none of the verts will have to be split to handle edge creases.

If you have manually edited normals in Maya (particularly flipped normals or used 'conform') you may find that importing the mesh without normals causes triangle to revert to their natural orientation - which may affect your culling.

So: using no normals is ok for the limited case of lightmapped unshaded geo, but not for much else.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" settings are specific to each model resource. If your mesh data represents a hard surface then you'll want to use the Maya smoothing angle so that you can fine-tune where the shading is blended in your output.

For organic shapes I've found that a smoothing angle of 89º is best but your mileage may vary (it's entirely dependent upon the visual output you're looking for.)

Normals have nothing to do with backface culling in Unity3d. If you don't need them to draw your content smoothly; then you can discard them altogether.

Comment: Actually I don't require Normals at all, as none of my Shaders use Normals, so should I just not import them in the Inspector.

Comment: I believe you're going to get normals if you don't import them. Calculating Normals would be an assertion.